# How to set multiple criteria for VLOOKUP function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data that is concatenated from other cells. Each cell lists the course number of a class, the room of the class and the start time of the class.
For example, a cell contains "B8007, WJW 200, Start Time: 9:00 AM"

Remember, this is concatenated from other cells.

My issue is that I am trying to perform a VLOOKUP from another tab in which I look up the room number and start time.

For example, =VLOOKUP (cell with room number, cell with start time)
However, each time I do this or any other variation, I get issues where it either returns it as N/A or shows me a lookup with a Start time that is not the start time I am actually looking up. 
EDIT:

=VLOOKUP("9:00",'Fall 2018 export - TEST'!AF2:AF4,1)

I read that it might be because the cell that is looking up the time, for example, is a number cell, while the cell I am looking up shows the time as a text. Even so, I still cannot get VLOOKUP to work.

Thank you

Comment: `=VLOOKUP (cell with room number, cell with start time)` is not the correct syntax for `VLOOKUP`. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54752612/edit) to give us the exact formula you are currently trying?

Answer (score 0):

Create another concatenated cell/column so that you can visually compare the two results where #N/A returns.  The problems can be widely varying, so having this direct comparison is important for you to be able to troubleshoot instance-by-instance.

You should be looking up a concatenated column to another concatenated column.  If you aren't doing that you're not going to get the result you're looking for.